# Direct way to measure perpendicular movement?

Tags: measurements, machine-design

I'm planning a CNC machine build which will use many [linear slides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-motion_bearing) with bearing blocks moving on them. Some of these need to be in parallel with each other and others perpendicular to each other.

It is easy to measure if two blocks move in parallel: mount dial indicator on one block and place the probe against the other block. Moving the blocks along the linear rails, the dial indicator reading should remain zero.

**Is there a way to directly measure if two blocks move perpendicularly?**

[image]

So far I've come up with two alternatives that are satisfactory, but I just wonder if there is a better alternative:

1. Measure perpendicularity to the surface of the linear rail: clamp an accurate machinist's square against one linear rail and measure if the movement on the other rail is parallel to the square. But the top surface of the linear rail is not necessarily perfectly parallel to the actual movement.
2. Measure movement of one block against a parallel reference surface. Then clamp a machinist's square on the reference surface and measure movement of the other block against that.

Comment: `top surface of the linear rail is not necessarily perfectly parallel to the actual movement` ... how do you expect to calibrate the machine if the quality of the components cannot be trusted?

Comment: your measurement of parallel rails is flawed ... you could raise one end of one of the rails and still measure the rails as parallel

Comment: calibrating the position of rail relative to another rail sounds like a recipe for constant headaches ... why don't you calibrate relative to a fixed point? ... make sure that the "orange" rail is vertical and the "blue" rail is horizontal ... double-check the relation between the two after the calibration is done ... you could use a laser level for this

Comment: jsotola's first comment +1. It isn't clear  to me what your concern is there. Is a level accurate enough? You can use a level on the horizontal rail as normal and clamp a square with a level onto the vertical rail. And check in 2-axis/planes  for both rails so you know the they aren't rotated but square relative to one another.

Comment: @jsotola Thanks for your comments, here is my reasoning: The bearing surface of the linear rail is not usually the top surface, and the top surface often has extra holes and plugs for attachment. It may be that it is not machined to the same standards as the rest of the part. For parallel rails, one needs to measure in two directions (vertical and horizontal) to verify parallelism in both of them, but both measurements can be done in the same way.

Comment: @DKNguyen Yes, a high accuracy machinist's level can be accurate enough. But that still only verifies the alignment of a surface, not the alignment of movement. I know, maybe I'm being too fussy with the distinction, but that is distinction between movement and surface is what I'm asking about.

Comment: Yes, if you have a known square reference block, then simply use a dial indicator as suggested. First set up the block to have a side parallel to the first axis, checking with dial indicator. Then without moving the block, check the second axis vs the second side. Creating a square object = exercise for reader